# C, Filling a 2D array by tokenizing string

Tags: c, arrays, io, tokenize

I'm trying to fill a 2d array by comma seperated integers.
I have already allocated the space for a 3x3 array. Now, I'm trying to loop through each line of input text to grab integers and place them in the array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    char currLine[257];
    char *token;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        fgets(currLine, 257, inputFile);

        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){

        }
}
```

The text is formatted as follows:

```
9,8,7
2,1,6
3,4,5
```

I can successfully grab each line, but from there I keep running into troubles. After I get each number, I of course want it to go into the [i][j] spot of the array. So the first line corresponds to [0] and the first value corresponds to [0][0].

Comment: What about `sscanf()`? `sscanf(currLine, "%d,%d,%d", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]); should do it, check that it returns `3`. Also, try to use another check, for example esnure that `fgets()` did read something, you can use `if (!feof(inputFile))` right after `fgets()` or better, check that `fgets()` does not return `NULL`.

Comment: I will give this a try. Though, I'm not familiar with how sscanf is formatted.

Comment: Well just [read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: You might be able to read directly from the file with `fscanf()`. No need to get it into a string with `fgets()` first.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizing the formatted text you provided is trivial. Take a look at the following code. You can change the code if your are targeting float numbers. In my code, I'm assuming integer numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* strlen() & memset() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* atoi() */

void getNumbers(const char* ch, int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int i;
    int size = strlen(ch) + 1;
    char ar[100];
    int n[3];

    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;


    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if( ch[i] != ',' )
            ar[j++] = ch[i];

        if ( ch[i] == ',' || i == size-1) {
            ar[j] = '\0';
            n[k++] = atoi(ar);
            memset(ar, 0, sizeof(ar));
            j = 0;
        }

    }

    *a = n[0];
    *b = n[1];
    *c = n[2];

}

int main()
{
  char *num = "1256,524,765";
  int n1,n2,n3;

  getNumbers(num,&n1, &n2, &n3);
  printf("%d  %d  %d\n", n1,n2,n3);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
1256  524  765
```